# Understanding the application layer in the osi model

Tags: networking, tcp, osi

I'm aware there are a lot of protocols at the application layer,

The question is more about when it is ok to not follow any of them,

Lets say i have a client and a server and the client app should send some data to that server, for instance, some statistics about a person using the app,

Now, for a good programming practice, is it ok to just open a tcp socket and send the data as is without the overhead of following a protocol or am i breaking the osi model and should i follow one of the protocols at the application layer? 
Am i reinventing the wheel here or is it a practical solution?

Comment: Nothing in the real world follows the OSI model, which, after all, is just a model. Your OS lumps layers 5, 6, and 7 into a single layer.

Comment: 'Breaking the model' is meaningless, especially as the OSI model was already broken ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's always an application layer protocol. If your concept is to transmit some statistics to a server ''on a certain TCP or UDP port as a plain, decimal number'' then that is your (implicit) application protocol. The protocol enables the server to receive data and assigns a meaning to the number.

The OSI model is a model, not a law. In your application layer protocol you can do whatever you want.

However, it may be useful to anticipate future expansion of the service, so that you could e.g. transmit `value_a:data\0value_b:data` in one stream/datagram without having to keep client and server versions in perfect sync  (with the server not expecting all values and just ignoring unknown values). Of course, you can also use a different server port each time instead - your choice.

Comment: And if i would like to follow a protocol from the known protocols list at the application layer for the above use case which should i choose?

Comment: You could select plain HTTP,  WebDAV, XMPP, SOAP, or even FTP for instance. Anything that suits your need.

Comment: If i need just to send a few numbers to the server can i do it with http?? if not is there any other protocol i can use?

Comment: Yes, see the list directly above. With HTTP, you could even transmit the actual data with a header entry (*X-age-value* or similar).